# Fixup commits that are non sequential

Tags: git

I am trying to wrap my head around git and rebaseing commits.  I understand how to take sequential commits and roll them up into one. However I am having a hard time figuring out how to roll separate commits into each other if they were not done in order.

Here is my interactive rebase:

```
pick 3327473e2 feature 1
pick 6f8b6bb5e feature 2
pick 440f987b0 my update to feature 2
pick 8b7d09e70 my update to feature 1
```

I am wanting to merge commit `8b7d09e70` into feature 1's commit. And I am wanting to merge `8b7d09e70` into feature 2's commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reorder the lines.

```
pick 3327473e2 feature 1
pick 8b7d09e70 my update to feature 1
pick 6f8b6bb5e feature 2
pick 440f987b0 my update to feature 2
```

Then change them to `squash` or  `fixup`:

```
pick 3327473e2 feature 1
fixup 8b7d09e70 my update to feature 1
pick 6f8b6bb5e feature 2
fixup 440f987b0 my update to feature 2
```